# What is the alternative to :dir() in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, right-to-left

I would like to know how we can implement this code to work in chrome browser,

```
/* Selects any element with right-to-left text */
:dir(rtl) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:dir
what is the alternative in Chrome Browser?

Comment: Is JavaScript an option, or must this be done with only HTML/CSS (even though I don't think that's possible currently, given the problems with the attribute-selector alternative in the MDN link in your post)?

Comment: actually I think of javascript as a solution, but the problem is that I need this in  javascript Credit Card module, adding javascript is a little bit problematic, trying to solve it,

Comment: @DavidThomas What "problems with the attribute-selector" are you referring to?

Comment: @TylerH: from the first **Note** in the linked document: "*Be aware that the behavior of the `:dir()` pseudo-class is not equivalent to the `[dir=…]` attribute selectors.*"

Comment: @DavidThomas That doesn't seem to be a *problem* with the attribute selector, just a warning not to mix up the two unrelated tools.

Comment: @TylerH, sure, but it does mean that using it as a solution leads to rather more work to implement a solution. I don't consider it unbearable, but it does add an extra step or so to the build process. Though perhaps my phrasing was poor, Maybe it should be considered a "caution," rather than a "problem"?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the [`dir` HTML attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir), you can use a [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to style that element accordingly. In case it is not obvious, this is *not* the same thing as the `:dir()` *pseudo-class* in CSS. Attribute selectors are widely supported across all modern browsers.

For Chrome, you may need to apply the element to the `<body>` instead, or be prepared to use `body { background-color: inherit; }`:

```css
html[dir="rtl"] {
    background-color: red;
}
body {
    background-color: inherit; /* Required for Chrome */
}
```

```html
<html dir="rtl">
    <body>
        <div>A red document background</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You don't have to apply it to the whole document either, of course. You can apply it to a specific element only:

```css
div[dir="rtl"] {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div>A white background</div>
        <div dir="rtl">A red background</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you would like to use JavaScript to detect the `dir` attribute, you can do so this way (or Google for your favorite way to detect an element via JS... there are at least half a dozen different ways):

```js
/* EcmaScript 6 required, which shouldn't be an issue for modern Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc. */
const doc = document.querySelector('html');

if (doc.hasAttribute('dir')) {
    const textDir = doc.getAttribute('dir');
    
    if (textDir == 'rtl') {
        doc.classList.add('rtl');
    } else {
        doc.classList.add('ltr');
    }
}
```

```css
.rtl {
    background-color: red;
}

body {
    background-color: inherit; /* again, only needed for Chrome */
}

.ltr {
    /* whatever styles you want for LTR text direction */
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html dir="rtl">
    <body>
        <div>A red document background</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: exactly what I want is something that solves my problem making the Css of that element different if the direction of the page is RTL

Comment: @mfadel And are you always setting that value yourself? E.g. can you rely on the fact that there would be a `dir=rtl` attribute somewhere that you set? If so you can detect it with JS (and I can update the answer to include a JS solution).

Comment: @TylerH actually it is set autoamtically on the html tag level not that element specifically

Comment: @mfadel I've added a JavaScript implementation to the answer; let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: thank you I will test it, although I changed to use a simpler form for the Credit Card so it is no longer needed, but I will test because this is important for me,

Answer (score 2):

`:dir()` is indeed very useful since it refers to the direction of the element even if inherited from the parent or ancestor, but unfouruntately it's only supported in Firefox as you mentioned.

`[dir="rtl"]` is supported cross-browser, but it only refers to elements that have this specifically. If the entire document is one direction and it is specified in either the `<html>` or `<body>` tag, then that's not a big problem since you can simply use the descendant selector. For example

```
[dir="rtl"] p {
    background: red;
}
```

However, this becomes complicated in a bidirectional document with nested sections. For example

```
<body dir="rtl">
  <p>עברית (RTL text)</p>
  <div dir="ltr">
    <p>English (LTR text)</p>
    <div dir="rtl">
      <p>עברית (another RTL text)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Sure, you can apply style rules to both directions like this

```
[dir="ltr"] p {
    background: green;
}

[dir="rtl"] p {
    background: red;
}
```

but CSS does not care which ancestor is closer, so the code above would still apply red to all paragraphs (and even reversing the order of rules wouldn't help for the nested section).

What you can do in this case is using CSS variables, which are inherited. For example

```
[dir="ltr"] {
    --p-background: green;
}

[dir="rtl"] {
    --p-background: red;
}

p {
  background: var(--p-background);
}
```

In this case the variable is applied directly to the element with the specified direction, then the variable value is inherited through the element chain the same way the direction itself does, and affects the styling of the element defined to use the variable value - in this example the `<p>` element.